# Use subjunctive for a definite event certain to happen after a series of events that should happen first?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, condicional, indicativa

Example:

> We first have to add enough oil, then put the corn seeds along with salt and put the cooking pan on the stove; wait a bit and those solid seeds will turn into a wonderful and funny popcorn.

Like which of the following suggested translations should the Spanish sentence be?

> Primero, debemos agregar una cantidad suficiente de aceite, y luego  poner el maíz y sal, y se pone la olla sobre la cocina; espera un poco y esas sólidas semillas se **convertirán**/**convirtieren**/**convertiría** en palomitas maravillosas y divertidas.

-The mentioned suggestions are: futuro indicativo, futuro subjuntivo and indicativo condicional, respectively.

*Please note that I do NOT want to use a keyword in this case, eg "when".*

Comment: Just noting that **espera** here is an *imperativo*, as in "wait a bit", not an *indicativo*; so does this still apply?

Comment: Yes, @Rotten is right. Future indicative will apply even if the imperative is used.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, when I wrote the English example I was thinking in the "present tense", and when I wrote the translation I was thinking in the "imperative". I'm glad it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Note the huge difference (grammatically) between *espera y se convertirán* (two independent clauses) and *espera a que see conviertan* (independent with subordinate). You can't use subjunctive in an independent clause

Comment: Just a tip: in multiple-choice questions like these, you can forget about the future subjunctive, unless it's an extremely formal (e.g. legal) text.

Comment: @pablodf76 I made up these examples. :D

Answer (score 1):

No, the subjunctive wouldn't be used for the final event.  Here's a typical pattern sentence that uses the subjunctive:

> Cuando hagas palomitas todos estarán contentos.

The subjunctive is used in the clause that sets up the *cause* in the *cause-and-effect*.

But note that the sentence could be rewritten in a way that doesn't use subjunctive, for example

> Si haces palomitas, todos estarán contentos.

My point is simply that the *result* clause wouldn't be in the subjunctive.